# Limit of Infinite Sum of Bessel Function of Second Kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I'm an engineer with not a strong math background. I am running into this expression when dealing with the wave equation in cylindrical coordinates. Does anyone one know how to evaluate this limit?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} Y_n(x) $$

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be good to have a little context as to where this comes from, as I am not sure that the question that you are asking is the one that you want to be asking. Each Bessel function $Y_n(x)$ tends to zero as $x\rightarrow \infty$ but that sum over $n$ does not converge, since $Y_n(x)$ does not tend to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$